# Variable declared with variable keyword in sql plus(oracle 9i)?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I am trying to declare  g_num ,number data type  with size  it gives an error but in case of varchar2,char it does not.

```
variable g_name varchar2(5);//correct accept size for varchar 2
variable g_num number(23);//Gives an error

    " VAR[IABLE] [ <variable> [ NUMBER | CHAR | CHAR (n [CHAR|BYTE]) |
              VARCHAR2 (n [CHAR|BYTE]) | NCHAR | NCHAR (n) |
              NVARCHAR2 (n) | CLOB | NCLOB | REFCURSOR ] ]"
```

Please suggest!

Answer (score 4):

The answer is already in your error message: `NUMBER` does not allow a precision in SQL*Plus.

```
VARIABLE g_num NUMBER;
```

works.

Here is a [list with valid variable declarations](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sqlplus/variable.html) in SQL*Plus.

The [documentation](http://download-west.oracle.com/docs/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b12170/ch13.htm#BACGHCJE) says:

> **NUMBER**
>   Creates a variable of type NUMBER with fixed length.

---

Unfortunately I don't know why you can't specify precision with SQL*Plus, but I have been able to store `1.0E+125` with my tests.

What do you need precision for?